# How to read all BIOS settings in Linux programmatically

Tags: linux, command-line, bios

I don't think that [dmidecode](https://man.archlinux.org/man/dmidecode.8.en) shows all the BIOS settings. Is there a way to read all the BIOS settings programmatically in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server?

Comment: Reading the EEPROM (where BIOS settings are stored, see https://superuser.com/questions/707254/where-is-the-bios-stored) might be one thing, decoding another. Probably differs between manufacturers a lot. :/

Comment: If you have UEFI firmware (i.e. not bios) you might see some stuff under `/sys/firmware/efi/vars/`.

Answer (score 3):

HP, DELL, IBM they all provide toolkit to export/import BIOS settings to/from a XML file. Check support/download page of your hardware model.

Comment: This worked for me for a couple Dell machines. I found "Dell Command | Configure". Works for latest Ubuntu versions from 16.04 to 20.04. I was able to read and configure my [AC power loss](https://superuser.com/a/1648187/318166) configuration this way.

Answer (score 1):

This thread helped me: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/viewing-bios-settings-from-within-linux-290492/

In essence, running [`dmidecode`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/dmidecode.8.en) as root generated lots of info on my system.

Answer (score 1):

## with [fwupd](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd)

Running `fwupdmgr get-bios-settings` produces a list of BIOS settings, such as these:

```
VirtualizationTechnology:
  Setting type:         Enumeration
  Current Value:        Enable
  Description:          VirtualizationTechnology
  Read Only:            False
  Possible Values:
    0:                  Disable
    1:                  Enable

HardwarePasswordManager:
  Setting type:         Enumeration
  Current Value:        Disable
  Description:          HardwarePasswordManager
  Read Only:            False
  Possible Values:
    0:                  Disable
    1:                  Enable

WakeOnLAN:
  Setting type:         Enumeration
  Current Value:        ACOnly
  Description:          WakeOnLAN
  Read Only:            False
  Possible Values:
    0:                  Disable
    1:                  ACOnly
    2:                  ACandBattery
    3:                  Enable
```